# What set is this bag from? Black, white, technic

Tags: set-identification

Here are some pictures of the front and back of the bag:

[image: this is a picture of the front of the bag]

[image: this is a picture of the back of the bag]

Answer (score 7):

It appears to be a bag from set [70815 Super Secret Police Dropship](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=70815-1).
[image: 70815]
I recognised these two parts from the bag:
[image: 15303][image: 32056]
and used [BrickLink's set finder](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogIn.asp?viewMulti=Y) to find sets with both parts.

Comment: Well! I had no idea BrickLink had such a thing, or I wouldn't have written my own.

Comment: I didn't know it existed either, until this question prompted me to see if it existed. There is a certain charm in using one's own code.